# Display description on click with multiple objects

Tags: angular

I am using Angular version 7. I have 6 buttons I 2 columns. I want to display a description of one of the buttons that are in the same div. Already I have achieved that all text is displayed when clicked in any button. How can I change that?

Here is the code:

```js
status: boolean = true;
  showDescription() {
    this.status = !this.status;
  }
}
```

```css
.shown {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.item__description {
                opacity: 0;
                transition: .5s ease;
                h4 {
                    font-size: 30px;
                    margin: 0 20px;
                }
                p {
                    color: #ffffff;
                    margin: 0 20px;
                }
            }
```

```html
<div class="content__left">
            <div class="content__item">
                <button (click)="showDescription()"><i class="fas fa-money-check-alt"></i></button>
                <div class="item__description" [ngClass]="status ? '' : 'shown'">
                    <h4>NAJLEPSZE CENY W REGIONIE</h4>
                    <p>Najwyższe ceny skupu złomu stalowego na Podlasiu</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" content__item ">
                <button (click)="showDescription()"><i class="fas fa-dolly "></i></button>
                <div class="item__description" [ngClass]="status ? '' : 'shown'">
                    <h4>TRANSPORT</h4>
                    <p>Posiadamy własną flotę pojazdów</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content__item ">
                <button (click)="showDescription()"><i class="fas fa-hand-holding "></i></button>
                <div class="item__description" [ngClass]="status ? '' : 'shown'">
                    <h4>KONTROLA ŁADUNKU</h4>
                    <p>Kontrolujemy cały proces załadunku i rozładunku</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I would suggest you extracting content__item div into separate component, that would have own state and showDescription defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comments, it seems to me you may want this instead.

```js
showMoneyCheckDescription = false;
showDollyDescription = false;
showHandHoldingDescription = false;
```

```css
.shown {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.item__description {
                opacity: 0;
                transition: .5s ease;
                h4 {
                    font-size: 30px;
                    margin: 0 20px;
                }
                p {
                    color: #ffffff;
                    margin: 0 20px;
                }
            }
```

```html
<div class="content__left">
            <div class="content__item">
                <button (click)="showMoneyCheckDescription = !showMoneyCheckDescription "><i class="fas fa-money-check-alt"></i></button>
                <div class="item__description" [ngClass]="showMoneyCheckDescription ? '' : 'shown'">
                    <h4>NAJLEPSZE CENY W REGIONIE</h4>
                    <p>Najwyższe ceny skupu złomu stalowego na Podlasiu</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" content__item ">
                <button (click)="showDollyDescription = !showDollyDescription"><i class="fas fa-dolly "></i></button>
                <div class="item__description" [ngClass]="showDollyDescription ? '' : 'shown'">
                    <h4>TRANSPORT</h4>
                    <p>Posiadamy własną flotę pojazdów</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content__item ">
                <button (click)="showHandHoldingDescription = !showHandHoldingDescription "><i class="fas fa-hand-holding "></i></button>
                <div class="item__description" [ngClass]="showHandHoldingDescription ? '' : 'shown'">
                    <h4>KONTROLA ŁADUNKU</h4>
                    <p>Kontrolujemy cały proces załadunku i rozładunku</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

### Original Answer

Try something like this, where you are not going to use a boolean flip variable, but instead a named item which indicates which section's description to show.

```js
itemToShow: string;
  showDescription(itemName: string) {
    if (this.itemToShow === itemName) {
        // if item that is showing was clicked again, then deselect
        this.itemToShow = null; // deselect
    } else {
        this.itemToShow = itemName; // select
    }
}
```

```css
.shown {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.item__description {
                opacity: 0;
                transition: .5s ease;
                h4 {
                    font-size: 30px;
                    margin: 0 20px;
                }
                p {
                    color: #ffffff;
                    margin: 0 20px;
                }
            }
```

```html
<div class="content__left">
            <div class="content__item">
                <button (click)="showDescription('money-check')"><i class="fas fa-money-check-alt"></i></button>
                <div class="item__description" [ngClass]="itemToShow === 'money-check' ? '' : 'shown'">
                    <h4>NAJLEPSZE CENY W REGIONIE</h4>
                    <p>Najwyższe ceny skupu złomu stalowego na Podlasiu</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" content__item ">
                <button (click)="showDescription('dolly')"><i class="fas fa-dolly "></i></button>
                <div class="item__description" [ngClass]="itemToShow === 'dolly' ? '' : 'shown'">
                    <h4>TRANSPORT</h4>
                    <p>Posiadamy własną flotę pojazdów</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content__item ">
                <button (click)="showDescription('hand-holding')"><i class="fas fa-hand-holding "></i></button>
                <div class="item__description" [ngClass]="itemToShow === 'hand-holding'? '' : 'shown'">
                    <h4>KONTROLA ŁADUNKU</h4>
                    <p>Kontrolujemy cały proces załadunku i rozładunku</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This is working well but how can i hide description again with click ? Edit: When you open one description and you try to open second the first one is hidding, but how can i with click on first button show and hide description ?

Comment: Also i would like to left description displayed if not clicked again.

Comment: @Ludar0 I edited the answer to put that in.  Ultimately, it is just about thinking of the property of itemToShow as if it were (which current item to I want to show) so if we want it to not show something, we can just set to null.

Comment: @Ludar0 I also gave you a different approach in case you are saying you want the showing of the description to be independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create an "accordion" component, that would have behaviour you need.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-accordion',
  template: `
     <div class="content__item ">
        <button (click)="showDescription()">
                  <i class="fas fa-hand-holding "></i>
        </button>
        <div class="item__description" [ngClass]="status ? '' : 'shown'">
           <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
     </div>
  `
})
export class AccordionComponent {
  public status = false;

  showDescription() {
    this.status = !this.status;
  }
}
```

And after you can use like this:

```
<ng-accordion>
  <h4>KONTROLA ŁADUNKU</h4>
  <p>Kontrolujemy cały proces załadunku i rozładunku</p>
</ng-accordion>
<ng-accordion>
  <h4>TRANSPORT</h4>
  <p>Posiadamy własną flotę pojazdów</p>
</ng-accordion>
```

Comment: This is a good answer to the issue, so long as you don't have the descriptions exclusive where when one shows the others should close.  Even then, this solution could be made to work and ultimately would be more clean.  Nice answer!